# Stuck on this complex number question

Tags: complex-numbers

I’m relatively new to complex numbers, and I don’t know how to solve this question. I know that $|w-3| = 2$ is a circle of radius $2$ with center $(3,0)$ but I’m not sure about the other one, and I don’t know how to find $\alpha$.

> There is a unique complex number $w$ that satisfies both $|w - 3| = 2$ and $\arg(w + 1) = \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a constant such that $0 < \alpha < \pi$.

Comment: The latter is a ray at angle $\alpha$ emanating from the point $-1$.

Comment: Thank you - what do you mean by emanating? Is it a half line that stops at the y axis and extends upwards?

Comment: It means starting from $-1$ (which is on the $x$-axis!) and extends upwards at angle $\alpha$. However, depending on the angle there may be $0,1$ or $2$ intersections, so it is not clear to me why it states that it is unique.

Comment: For z a complex number, arg(z) is the angle the line from 0 to z, in the complex plane makes with the real axis. "$arg(w+ 1)= \alpha$ means that w lies on thine through the origin has slope $tan(\alpha)$ so, writing z= x+ iy, has equation $y= tan(\alpha)x$.  You want the value of z= x+ iy satisfying $(x- 3)^2+ y^2= 4$, $y= tan(\alpha)x$ that is in the upper half plane.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think I’m just too thick to understand! should I plug in y=tan(a)x into the first equation to solve for x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The circle is the locus of points $w$ such that $|w-3|=2$. The upper of the two parallel lines is the locus of points $w$ such that arg($w+1)=\alpha$. The points on the lower parallel line are the points with arg $\alpha$ ($\alpha$ is the angle between the line and the real axis). Or more accurately, the points on the ray from the origin into the upper left quadrant have arg $\alpha$. The points on the other half of the line have arg outside the range $0$ to $\pi$.

You can see that if we reduce $\alpha$ from the angle shown, then the upper line intersects the circle in two points. If we increase $\alpha$ then the line does not intersect the circle.

You want the value of $\alpha$ which gives a unique $w$, so it just remains to calculate the angle. It is in a right-angled triangle. The hypotenuse is length 4 (from -1 to 3) and the opposite side is length 2 (the radius). So $\sin\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ and hence $\alpha=30^\circ=\pi/6$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This made it really clear. I was really struggling with complex numbers and this helped a lot :)

Comment: would you happen to know how to express w in the form r(cosθ+isinθ) ? If not, no worries

Comment: The real part of $w$ is 2 and the imaginary part is $i\sqrt3$. So it is $r=\sqrt7$ and $\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$,